# The page moves to the left

Tags: css

[this is how it looks on pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6adSq.png)

[this is how it looks on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf087.png)
because you see run to the left on mobile

link: https://binarytreecode.github.io/Textiles/index.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please visit this page: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to clearly state your problem and provide some minimal code so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The page is stuck to the left side (on mobile) because the video block is too wide. Set styles for `video` .